# Java File Handling DisplayOnConsole

Tags: java, file-handling

Question – File Handling [20 pts]

Given the following data about some account information of First National bank customers:

111111  john smith   500

222222  mark smith  1500

333333  steve jones  2000

444444  mary jones  1000

```
           Write a Java program that:
```

a.    Writes the above data into file “payroll.txt”.

b.    Reads the above data from “payroll.txt”.

c.    Displays on java console the account information of each customer as follows:

Account 1  id: 111111  name: john smith  balance: 500 $

Account 2 id: 222222  name: mark smith  balance: 1500 $

```
 Account 3 id: 333333  name: steve jones  balance: 2000 $
```

Account 4 id:444444  name: mary jones  balance: 1000 $

d.    Calculate and display the total balance of all customers:
   Total balance of all accounts is 5000 $

---

i could only do part a & b i need help in part c & d please

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FileHandling {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("payroll.txt");
        out.println("111111 john smith 500");
        out.println("222222 mark smith 1500");
        out.println("333333 steve jones 2000");
        out.println("444444 mary jones 1000");
        out.close();
        Scanner in=new Scanner("payroll.txt");
        while (in.hasNext()){
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

c.

```
System.out.println("Account 1 id 111111 name: john smith balance: 500 $");
System.out.println("Account 2 id 222222 name: mark smith balance: 1500 $");
System.out.println("Account 3 id 333333 name: steve jones balance: 2000 $");
System.out.println("Account 4 id 444444 name: mary jones balance: 1000 $");
```

If you have the variables data, you can replace each id, name and balance directly from the variables using String concatenation.

d.

```
int totalBalance = 500 + 1500 + 2000 + 1000;
System.out.println("Total balance of all accounts is " + totalBalance + " $");
```